# How to get particular value from array object in controller LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have an object like this

```
object = [{ value: "new" Label: "New", state: "active"},
 {value: "pending" Label: "Pending", state:   "active"} ,
 {value: "closed" , Label: "Closed" , state: "inactive" } ];
```

I have a field called  currentValue which holds the value like

```
currentValue = pending ;
```

With the value  of currentValue I need to fetch it's state from the above object
Like currentValue = pending
From the object the state for pending is active.
How do I fetch it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `array.prototype.find` should do it:

```
const filtered = yourobj.find( (obj) => {
  return ( obj.value === 'pending' &&  obj.state === 'active'); );
});
```

If you need dynamic `find` params, you can do this:

```
let findVal = 'pending';
let findState = 'active';
const filtered = yourobj.find( (obj) => {
  return ( obj.value === findVal &&  obj.state === findState); );
});
```

Or `filter` (returns an array, not a single object):

```
const filtered = yourobj.filter( (obj) => {
  return ( obj.value === 'pending' &&  obj.state === 'active'); );
});
```

Note, these approaches work because you actually have an `Array` not an `Object`

Comment: I mean like if(obj.value =='pending) then I need to get obj.state of that pending

Comment: Once you have run `find` and have your `filtered` object - just get it's `state` property - `let state = filtered.state;`. You may want to edit the filter function to remove the reqirement for `state == 'active'`.